# Proving that $T_v$ is unique , $T_v$ here is derivation on $\mathbb{C}^{\infty} (U)$

Tags: analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am studying from class notes of Smooth manifolds and I was unable to solve this paricular question left as an exercise.

Define $T_v : C^{\infty}(U) \to \mathbb{R} $ by $T_v(f)= v(f) = \frac{d}{dt} f(p+tv)|_{t=0}$.Also, $T_v(f) =df_p(v)=\frac{df}{dx_1}(p) v_1 +...+ \frac{df}{dx_n} (p)v_n$  --(1)

> Now let $T: C^{\infty}(U) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear map which satisfies Liebnitz rule ie T(fg)=f(p)T(g) + g(p) T(f). Then $T= T_v$ for some unique $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I have only question in uniqueness. I took $T_v =T_w$ , which implies $\frac{df}{dx_1}(p) (v_1 -w_1)+...+\frac{df}{dx_n}(p)(v_n -w_n)=0$. But I am not able to understand how should I prove $v_i =w_i $ for all i from 1 to n.

Can you please help.

Comment: Can you (for some fixed $i$) find an $f\in C^\infty(U)$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p)=1$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}(p)=0$ for $j\neq i$?

Comment: @Kajelad  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The name is [Leibniz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Wilhelm_Leibniz).

Comment: @No-One If you can find such an $f$, the equation you've written gives $T_vf=T_wf\implies v_i=w_i$. If you can do this for each $i$, you are done. Notice also that the coordinate function $x_i$ suffices locally, so you just need to extend them.

Comment: @Kajelad Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: @PaulFrost Can you please write an answer?

Comment: You should edit your question to explain what $U$ and $v$ are. And what is $df_p$ in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough you do not mention it in your question, I think $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, $v \in \mathbb R^n$ and $df_p : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ denotes the usual derivative (which is a linear map) of a smooth function $f : U \to \mathbb R$ in the sense of multivariable calculus.

$\frac{d}{dt} f(p+tv)|_{t=0}$ is the usual directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in direction $v$. It is well-known that
$$\frac{d}{dt} f(p+tv)|_{t=0} = df_p(v) .$$
Representing $df_p$ by the Jacobian matrix $Jf_p$ and writing $v$ as a column vector gives
$$df_p(v) = Jf_p \cdot v = \frac{df}{dx_1}(p) v_1 +...+ \frac{df}{dx_n} (p)v_n .$$

You want to show that $T_v = T_w$ implies $v = w$. As you say, $T_v = T_w$ means that
$$\frac{df}{dx_1}(p) (v_1-w_1) +...+ \frac{df}{dx_n} (p)(v_n-w_n) = 0 \tag{$*$}$$
for **all** $f$.

Let $\pi_i : U \to \mathbb R,\pi(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = x_i$, denote the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate. Then $\frac{d\pi_i}{dx_j}(p) = 1$ for $j = i$ and  $\frac{d\pi_i}{dx_j}(p) = 0$ for $j \ne i$. Thus $(*)$ gives $v_i - w_i = 0$, i.e. $v_i = w_i$.