# How to prove that there exists a p such that $df_p$ exists

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds

This question is from the notes I am reading and I was unable to prove it.

So, I am looking for help here.

> Let M be the compact manifold and $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Prove that there exists a point $p\in  M$ such that $df_p$ is zero linear transformation.

Attempt: $df_p(v)=\frac{d f(p+tv)}{dt}|_{t=0}$ is a map from $C^{\infty}(U) \to \mathbb{R}$.But How do I use the that f is smooth and M is compact to find p? I don't know?

Please guide.

Comment: The function must attain a maximum.

Comment: @Randall Can you please elaborate on your comment ? I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the hint by Randall: Since $M$ is compact there exists a point $p\in M$ such that $f$ attains its maximum at $p$. Let $v\in T_pM$ be arbitrary. Suppose that $\gamma :(-\varepsilon , \varepsilon) \to M$ is such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$. The definition of $df_p(v)$ is precisely $$df_p(v) =(f\circ \gamma)'(0) . $$ Since $f$ attains its maximum at $p$, $t\mapsto (f\circ \gamma)(t)$ attains a maximum at $t=0$. Thus, we have $(f\circ \gamma)'(0)=0$ and so $df_p(v)=0$. Since $v$ was arbitrary, we have that $df_p$ is the zero map.

Notes: 1. you have written $$df_p(v) = \frac{d f(p+tv)}{dt} \bigg \vert_{t=0} $$ which is not correct. There is no concept of addition on a general manifold.

Comment: how does M being compact implies that there exists a point $p\in M$ such that f attains it's maximum at p? Kindly tell what definition of compact you are using.

Comment: It follows from the extreme value theorem. The definition of compactness is every open cover of $M$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: How are you sure that such a $\gamma$ exists?

Comment: Let $\varphi : U\subset  M \to \mathbb R^n$ be local coordinates of $M$ such that $p\in U$ and $\varphi(p)=0$. Write $v=v^i d/dx^i \big \vert_p$ (using the summation convention) with each $v^i\in \mathbb R$ and choose $\varepsilon>0$ sufficiently small such that $(tv^1,\dots,tv^n) \in \varphi(U)$ for all $\vert t \vert <\varepsilon$. Then $\gamma (t) = \varphi^{-1} (tv^1,\dots,tv^n)$ is such a curve.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291648/proving-that-t-v-is-unique-t-v-here-is-derivation-on-mathbbc-infty  Do you mind looking at this question of mine too?

Comment: Thank you very much!